# Why two calls to HttpSendRequest on different connections (new InternetOpen and new InternetConnect) bring different results?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, request, wininet

I'm using wininet to connect to a URL that needs a client certificate. To test my "automatic error correction", I'm doing this connection without the client certificate and the behaviour is to call my SelectCertificate function.

Intentionally I do not pass all the parameter to this function which, of course, raises an exception and my request is aborted. There are cleaning blocks to do all the necessary cleaning [InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpenRequestHandle), InternetCloseHandle(InternetConnectHandle) and InternetCloseHandle(InternetOpenHandle)].

The first request is returning the correct exception, caused by the lack of a client certificate, but the second (new?) request is raising another exception "Secure Channel Support Error" (error 12157)

To clarify, see the following flow:

The first request

```
1.0 InternetOpen(...)

2.0 InternetConnect(...)

3.0 HttpOpenRequest(...)

4.0 HttpSendRequest(..)

  4.1 Error (ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED)

  4.2 SelectCertificate

    4.2.1 Raise exception because I intentionally do not passed all parameters

5.0 InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpenRequestHandle)

6.0 InternetCloseHandle(InternetConnectHandle)

7.0 InternetCloseHandle(InternetOpenHandle);
```

The second (new?) request

```
1.0 InternetOpen(...)

2.0 InternetConnect(...)

3.0 HttpOpenRequest(...)

4.0 HttpSendRequest(..)

  4.1 Error (ERROR_INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR)

  4.2 I do not know how to handle this error, so...

  4.3 Raise the original exception "Secure Channel Support Error"

5.0 InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpenRequestHandle)

6.0 InternetCloseHandle(InternetConnectHandle)

7.0 InternetCloseHandle(InternetOpenHandle)
```

All other requests from now are just like the second one.

My questions are:

As I'm closing all the handles and doing a "totally new connection", the results between the calls should not be the same?

If not, why?

And there are a way to do an all new connection? How?

Actually, I only get a totally new connection by closing the entire application and starting over

Comment: To those are voting to close my question because it is "out of programming  context", read it carefully. I do "lost" time to try to explain my problem and it IS a programming question because I want to know why this behaviour is happening. There are no code, because this is not necessary yet. Pay attention to the workflow. It contains API functions, so... It's a programming question. People working with wininet surely know that this can happening and can help-me. I can read C, C++, Delphi and VB, so, solutions on any of these languages can help-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by some kind of SSL cache, wich can be erased by executing the following code block BEFORE the request:

```
type
    TSslEmptyCache = function (pszTargetName: LPSTR; dwFlags: DWORD): BOOL; WINAPI;
    TIncrementUrlCacheHeaderData = function (nIdx: DWORD; lpdwData: LPDWORD): BOOL; WINAPI;

var
    SchannelDLLHandle, WinInetHandle: HMODULE;
    SslEmptyCache: TSslEmptyCache;
    IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData: TIncrementUrlCacheHeaderData;

SchannelDLLHandle := LoadLibrary('schannel.dll');
WinInetHandle := LoadLibrary('wininet.dll');

if (SchannelDLLHandle > 0) and (WinInetHandle > 0) then
    try
    SslEmptyCache := GetProcAddress(SchannelDLLHandle,'SslEmptyCacheW');
    IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData := GetProcAddress(WinInetHandle,'IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData');
    if Assigned(SslEmptyCache) and Assigned(IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData) then
    begin
      SslEmptyCache(nil,0);
      IncrementUrlCacheHeaderData(14,@buffer);
    end;
    finally
        FreeLibrary(SchannelDLLHandle);
    FreeLibrary(WinInetHandle);
    end;
```

For more information, read [this article](http://www.zettaomnis.net.br/portal/zost-mei/articles-zost-mei/149-o-limite-da-persistencia-ao-buscar-uma-solucao.html).